# If $f$ and $g$ are both continuous, then the functions $\max\{f,g\}$ and $\min\{f,g\}$ are also continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, alternative-proof, maxima-minima

Let $X$ be a subset of $\textbf{R}$, and let $f:X\to\textbf{R}$ and $g:X\to\textbf{R}$ be functions. Let $x_{0}\in X$. Then if $f$ and $g$ are both continuous at $x_{0}$, then the functions $\max\{f,g\}$ and $\min\{f,g\}$ are also continuous at $x_{0}$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Once one knows the identities
\begin{align*}
\max\{a,b\} = \frac{a + b + |a-b|}{2}\quad\wedge\quad\min\{a,b\} = \frac{a + b - |a-b|}{2}
\end{align*}

we can argue the continuity of the functions $\max\{f,g\}$ and $\min\{f,g\}$ as a consequence of composition of continuous functions.

My question is: is there another way to prove it without appealing to such identities? (Or one way which deduces them at least).

**EDIT**

As commented by @GEdgar, the continuity of $|\cdot|$ has already been proved.

Comment: You can unravel the inequalities involved in the definition of continuity, but the identities you wrote seem perfectly fine for the task.

Comment: For your attempt you need to know that $|x|$ is continuous.  If you are assuming that is already known, you should mention it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of deduce these identities:

> It is easy to see that $\max\{f,g\} + \min\{f,g\} = f+g$ and that $\max\{f,g\} - \min\{f,g\} = |f-g|$. Adding both equalities and dividing by $2$ we obtain the first identity, and substracting the second from the first one, and again dividing by $2$, we obtain the second identity.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x_0) > g(x_0)$ then let $\epsilon = \frac {f(x_0) - g(x_0)}2$.  Then as $f,g$ are continuous there are $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ where $|x- x_0| < \min(\delta_1, \delta_2) \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| <\epsilon, |g(x)-g(x_0)| < \epsilon$ which means $f(x) > f(x_0) - \epsilon = \frac {f(x_0) + g(x_0)}2$ and $g(x) < g(x_0) + \epsilon = \frac {f(x_0) + g(x_0)}2 < f(x)$.

So $\min{f,g}(x) = g(x)$ which is continuous at $x$ and $\max{f,g}(x) =f(x)$ which is continuous at $x$.

Equivalent argument thing if $f(x_0) < g(x_0)$.

And if $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$ then for any $\epsilon >0$ there are $\delta_1, \delta_2$ so that $|x-x_0| < \min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$ then $|f(x)- f(x_0)| = |f(x) - \min{f,g}(x_0)| < \epsilon$ and $|g(x)- g(x_0)| = |g(x) - \min{f,g}(x_0)| < \epsilon$ so $|\min{f,g}(x) - \min{f,g}(x_0)| < \epsilon$ and $|\max{f,g}(x) - \max{f,g}(x_0)| < \epsilon$.  So $\min{f,g}$ and $\max{f,g}$ are continuous.

====

All said and done my idea was the first thing I would have thought of...

But your idea is clever and easier. Aziff00 is perhaps the easiest and cleverest but it is essentially yours.

Comment: It is good to learn how to do these $\epsilon, \delta$ arguments.

Comment: Well, my *very* first thought was to to use the intermediate value theorem that there are no points of discontinuity where $\min/\max fg$ will jump from $f$ to $g$  except where $f(x)=g(x) = 0$ and so $\max|\min fg$ would be either $f$ or $g$ on intervals where they are continuous and only "switch" on points where they equal to zero but putting all *that* together....